# How to translate a QQuickItem's position into its new parent

Tags: qt, qml, qquickitem

I have 2 `QQuickItem`s like below which I can fetch on C++ side using the `QMLEngine` like this.

```
QQuickItem * quick_item_1 = m_qml_engine->rootObjects()[0]->findChild<QQuickItem*>("quickitem1");
QQuickItem * quick_item_2 = m_qml_engine->rootObjects()[0]->findChild<QQuickItem*>("quickitem2");
```

**Note:** `quick_item_1`'s immediate parent is *different* & `quick_item_2`'s immediate parent is also different. *But* they both are drawn on the same application window into different immediate parents.

I am drawing both of them offscreen on a different `QQuickItem`. Let's call it `new_parent_surface`. I draw both these items on `new_parent_surface` by changing their parent to `new_parent_surface` like this.

```
quick_item_1->setParentItem(new_parent_surface);
quick_item_2->setParentItem(new_parent_surface);
```

**This works fine for the objective of drawing them on a new parent QQuickItem**. I get the both `quick_item_1` & `quick_item_2` drawn on `new_parent_surface`. Even though `new_parent_surface` is not drawn on UI, but if I take a snapshot using [grabToImage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#grabToImage-method) of `new_parent_surface`, I can see the 2 items drawn on them. Fine till here.

However the **positioning** of `quick_item_1` & `quick_item_2` is not correct. I want to position them similar to the way they were positioned their original parent item. I can do some percentage math & try positioning them the same way as they were drawn on their original parent **but isn't there a QQQuickItem or Qt API to translate this positioning to a new parent?**

I tried to look into QQuickItem's mapping APIs like [mapToItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#mapToItem) & trying them out like this.

```
quick_item_2->mapToItem(new_parent_surface, quick_item_2->position());
```

But the positioning is still not correct.

So, **how** can I map a QQuickItem's position into its new parent QQuickItem after doing a [setParentItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#parent-prop)?

Comment: `QQuickItem` has lots of `mapTo*()` and `manFrom*()` functions. Btw, next time just put here your code instead of explaining it.

Comment: understand @folibis. due to other things going around in the code, I thought it will be better to describe the relevant issue. btw, if I try `setPosition` with some values then of course I can position `quick_item_2` as ever I want. But I was interested in knowing if there is a recommended QQuickItem API to do this

Answer (score 1):

`Item`s position is always relative to its parent. And position of the parent is relative to its parent and and so on. But you always can get both relative or global position. QML has lots of coordination translation function. Here is small example that could explain the issue:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1

Window {
    id:container
    width: 800
    height: 800
    visible: true

    Component {
        id: rect
        Rectangle {
            property bool imParent: false
            x: 50 + Math.round(Math.random() * 550)
            y: 50 + Math.round(Math.random() * 550)
            width: 100 + Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
            height: 100 + Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
            color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1);
            Drag.active: dragArea.drag.active
            MouseArea {
                id: dragArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                drag.target: parent
            }
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: imParent ? "I'm parent" : "Drag me"
                color: "white"
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: blk
        x: 10
        y: 10
        z: 100
        parent: null
        height: 50
        width: 50
        radius: 5
        border.color: "white"
        color: "black"

    }

    Repeater {
        id: reptr
        model: 5
        property int pos: 0
        Loader {
            id: loader
            sourceComponent: rect
            onLoaded: {
                if(blk.parent == null) {
                    blk.parent = loader.item;
                    loader.item.imParent = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Row {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: container.contentItem.horizontalCenter
        spacing: 2
        Button {
            text: "Reparent relative to parent"
            onClicked: {
                reptr.pos ++;
                if(reptr.pos >= reptr.model) {
                    reptr.pos = 0;
                }
                var item = reptr.itemAt(reptr.pos).item;
                blk.parent.imParent = false;
                blk.parent = item;
                blk.parent.imParent = true;
            }
        }
        Button {
            text: "Reparent relative to scene"
            onClicked: {
                reptr.pos ++;
                if(reptr.pos >= reptr.model) {
                    reptr.pos = 0;
                }
                var item = reptr.itemAt(reptr.pos).item;
                var coord = blk.mapToGlobal(blk.x, blk.y);
                blk.parent.imParent = false;
                blk.parent = item;
                blk.parent.imParent = true;
                coord = blk.mapFromGlobal(coord.x, coord.y);
                blk.x = coord.x;
                blk.y = coord.y;
            }
        }
    }
}
```